# how to use 2 getx controllers inside each other?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I would like to use 2 controllers inside each other, but the problem is that one of them has to be initialized before the other one. For example

```
class FirstController extends GetxController {
  SecondController _secondController = Get.find<SecondController>(); 
}
```

```
class SecondController extends GetxController {
  FirstController _firstController = Get.find<FirstController>();
}
```

I used both put and lazyPut but nothing worked for me. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: This seems like a deadlocked situation. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you mean accessing one controller directly from another controller class, then yes you can. But obviously not both at the same time

Comment: what I am trying to do is to reset a value in page 2 depending on user action in page on. so for example let's say that I am asking the user to choose either x or y in page 1, and in page 2 there is an option to increment x or y counter by 1, and the max value for x is 3 and the max value for y is 2. So what I am trying to do is to reset the counter value so that when the user change x or y he would no be able to proceed with a value more than the max value. I hope my explanation is clear

Comment: See from what you are currently doing is a deadlock situation you cannot control both of them simultaneously. Access only one controller directly from another controller class. By this I mean, you can pass some values from one controller which can be controlled by another.

Comment: will try that, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Anytime ! Let me know if you face any more problems

Comment: thanks a lot! I managed to solve this problem by removing the variable and using the controller directly in the method!

Comment: Please answer it out so that it would be helpful for future developers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I managed to solve this problem by removing the declaration of the second controller in the first controller, and used this inside a method.

```
void myMethod()
{
Get.find<SecondController>().methodName();
}
```